# In HTML code use another data tag in href=Variable

Tags: html, href

```
<!-- Section: /report/detail -->
<xsl:template match="/report/detail">
 <div href="./lf_web" style="left: 0.0ex; position: absolute"><xsl:value-of select="./lf_po"/></div>
 <br/>
</xsl:template>
```

In this code I am trying to use the content of the taq element "`./lf_web`".

Can any one help me please.

It is in and .xsl file and linked to .xml data source

Answer (score 0):

You should tag your question with XSL instead of **div** and **href** which are not important to your question.

One way is to first retrieve the value in a variable. I like that way because you can use functions:

```
<xsl:variable name="website_uri" as="xs:string">
     <xsl:value-of select="info/uri"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="protocol" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($website_uri, '://')"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

And I show how you use a variable: with a $ sign before the name of the value. However, to do so inside a *different* attribute, you need to put it between curly brackets;

```
<a href="{$url}">...</a>
```

Now I think you can do the query you're trying to achieve inline too, but I don't see a good example for it.

Comment: The reason for this example is that the data looks like this in the xml file

Comment: <detail tag="0">
<lf_po>12345</lf_po><lf_web>http://www.scopesystems.com.au</lf_web>
</detail>